# Can't build flutter when I use mobile Emulator

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

I am going to build my flutter project using the mobile emulator, but it shows:
":\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"

But if I run it with the web, no errors will pop up. However, no content shows in the web tab.
Here is the flutter doctor:[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1586])[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc1)[√] Chrome - develop for the web[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)[√] Connected device (3 available).

So, how could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to your system environment. Because your system is not able to find the folder where you have installed Flutter in your system.
[for more details](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows)